# Jquery: How to process a div after you have appended or set data to it optimally

Tags: jquery, optimization, css-selectors

I think this question is better served with an example. I have the following code:

> $.get('path/'+id,function(data){
>                       $('#mydiv').html(data);
>                       $('.editable').button().click(function(){
>                           //process here
>                       });
>                   });

And it works just fine; however, I think it would be more optimal to only go through "mydiv" when I call $('.editable') rather than through the whole page without even finding "mydiv" again. Example of what I think should work:

> $('#mydiv').html(data).$('.editable').button().click(function(){
>                           //process here
>                       });
>                   });

In other words, I suppose after completing its work with the html function I can perform another action on this div. Is this possible? Sorry if this seems odd and convoluted.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var my_div = $('#mydiv');
$.get('path/'+id,function(data){
    my_div.html(data)
        .find('.editable')
        .button()
        .click(function(){
            //process here
        });
});
```